# Write Message to MQ as ASCII using C#

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I have a string that is in the form of XML or any string for that matter and I am getting the BOM when it is written to MQ. I was trying to convert the string to ASCII in the C# application  but it still showed in the message in MQ.
I thought i could use the Encoding method in the MQMessage()

```
MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager();
queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(QueueName,
               MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
message = strInputMsg;
queueMessage = new MQMessage();
queueMessage.WriteString(message);
queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
queueMessage.Encoding = MQC.MQENC_NATIVE;

queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();

queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
```

I am not sure what the value for the queueMessage.Encoding line should be.

another question will the Encoding to ASCII remove the Bit Object Mark(BOM)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if this gets fixed at the source where strInputMsg is created? Because then you can use any or all of the solutions available: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+remove+BOM

Comment: I tried to convert the string to UTF8 and to ASCII by converting to a byte array but the MQ message still displays the BOM.

Comment: From memory, I think you need to set queueMessage.CodedCharSetId = 850 before the 'WriteString' call, but am not able to verify that myself at present

Comment: That worked. thank you

Comment: Thanks - I'll move it to an answer, if you wouldnt mind accepting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111220_.htm

> ReadString, ReadLine and WriteString methods convert between Unicode
>   and the character set of the message; see CharacterSet

and

> The WriteString method converts from Unicode to the character set
>   encoded in CharacterSet. If CharacterSet is set to its default value,
>   MQC.MQCCSI_Q_MGR, which is 0, no conversion takes place and
>   CharacterSet is set to 1200. If you set CharacterSet to some other
>   value, WriteString converts from Unicode to the alternate value.

So in effect before you call WriteString, you have a unicode string in .NET. The WriteString method converts from that unicode into the CCSID indicated by the CharacterSet property, which defaults to unicode and gives you the funny 2 byte prefix of the byte order mark (BOM). If you set this to e.g. 850, then it will convert from unicode to a single byte ASCII output as you want.